# How to boot from DVD in Lenovo Y560 laptop

Tags: windows-8, boot, multi-boot, dvd, lenovo-laptop

I'm trying to install Windows 8 from a DVD in my Lenovo Y560 laptop. However I'm unable to boot from DVD no matter what boot sequence I put. These are the following options I have.

```
1: USB KEY :
2: USB HDD :
3: USB FDC :
4: IDE 0 :
5. IDE 1 : WDC WD5000BEVT-24A0RT0
6. IDE CD : SlimtypeDVD A DS8A4S
7. USB CDROM : 
8. PCI BEV: MBA v12.2.5 Slot 0900
```

Can someone please help me out with this as to what order I need to put or if I'm missing out on doing something??

Thank you.!

Comment: put USB CDROM in #1 and try again

Comment: Tried.. Didn't boot :-( Windows started normally..

Comment: by the way, win8 can be installed like a normal setup ... is it a must that you have to boot from dvd to install it?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be installed right? booting from dvd? Direct setup works? I'm not aware of that.....

Comment: ya.. if you are already on windows, insert dvd, open it, you will see setup.exe .. thats it

Comment: `USB CDROM` won't work for this as I doubt the drive in your computer is connected via USB. The option you want is `IDE CD`. Lenovos often have a strange way of dealing with boot sequences, often there will be more than one boot sequence that you can configure. Make sure you are using the 'Standard' sequence if it's available.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I tried by putting the IDE CD in the first position. But it did not boot from the CD. In fact, I put only IDE CD in the list and excluded all others from the boot sequence. Then it said "Operating System not found". I guess for some reason my laptop is not able to detect the DVD/CD

Comment: That would suggest to me that the DVD itself is not bootable. Can you try it in another PC to make sure?

Comment: @MAKZ Thanks a lot! You were right. I could run the setup directly from the DVD without bothering about the boot sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 can be installed directly from the DVD by running the setup file from the DVD itself. No need to change boot sequence and all that. Just put the DVD in while running your OS and then directly run the setup. Windows 8 will get installed on your PC.

Thanks to the commentators.

Hope this helps.!